# Como pasar el valor de un ID a una variable PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]hola llevo ya varios dias con este problema y he consultado por todos lados y nadie sabe ayudarme estoy realizando una pagina en donde quiero que el usuario pueda escoger una opcion y dependiendo de la opcion aparezcan otras opciones(select multiple) y que las opciones que el usuario escoja yo las pueda almacenar en una variable php para luego almacenarla en la BD,esto lo estoy haciendo con php y ajax mi problema es en el ajax ya que no puedo pasar el valor almacenado en el ID y llevarlo a PHP

dejo el codigo php

envio.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>empresa</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">

  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <?php
  session_start();

  ?>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo.jpg">
  </div>

  <header>
    <nav class="navegacion">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="">Envio de Sangre</a></li>
        <li><a href="soli_despacho.php">Despacho </a></li>
          <li><a href="stacces.php">Servicios en Transitos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
<center>
  <h1 style="font-size: 16px;">Envio de sangre</h1><br><br>

  <h2>Envio de Sangre Completa</h2><br><br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <p>Cantidad de coolers
          <select id="cantidad" name="cantidad" class="form-control">
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p>Coolers
        <select id="coolers" name="coolers" class="form-control">
        </select>
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><br><button id="enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">Enviar</button></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><b>El resultado es: </b></p><p id="resultado1"></p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>

  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

este es el codigo ajax

index.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'cargar_listas.php'
  })
  .done(function(listas_rep){
    $('#cantidad').html(listas_rep)
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Hubo un errror al cargar la cantidad')
  })

  $('#cantidad').on('change', function(){
    var id = $('#cantidad').val()
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'cargar_coolers.php',
      data: {'id': id}
    })
    .done(function(listas_rep){
      $('#coolers').html(listas_rep)
    })
    .fail(function(){
      alert('Hubo un errror al cargar los coolers')
    })
  })

  $('#enviar').on('click', function(){
    var resultado = 'Cantidad: ' + $('#cantidad option:selected ').text() +
    ' Coolers elegido: ' + $('#coolers option:selected').text()
    $('#resultado1').html(resultado);

    $.post( "pagina.php", {resultado:resultado});
  });

});
```

estos los archivos de procesos

cargar_listas.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'conexion2.php';
function getListasRep(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `cantidad`';
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $listas = '<option value="0">Elige cantidad</option>';

  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $listas .= "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[cantidad]</option>";

  }
  return $listas;
}
echo getListasRep();
?>
```

cargar_coolers.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'conexion2.php';
function getVideos(){
  $mysqli = getConn();
  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `coolers` WHERE id_lista = $id";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query);
  $videos = '<option value="0">Elige una opción</option>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $videos .= "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[cooler]</option>";

  }
  return $videos;
}
echo getVideos();
?>
```

y este es el archivo php a donde estoy enviando el id para pasarlo a php

pagina.php

```
<?php

    $resultado = $_POST["resultado"];
    print($resultado);

?>
```

aclaro un poco lo que hace el codigo, la funcion del codigo es darle al usuario escoger una opcion y dependiendo de que elija saldran otras opciones el funcionamiento del Select esta completamente bien y el de el AJAX igual esta perfecto ahora en funcion del ajax al fina esta este codigo

```
$('#enviar').on('click', function(){
    var resultado = 'Cantidad: ' + $('#cantidad option:selected ').text() +
    ' Coolers elegido: ' + $('#coolers option:selected').text()
    $('#resultado1').html(resultado);
```

aqui es donde asigo a RESULTADO como la variable que contendra todos los valores selecionado y son pasados al id en esta parte $('#resultado1').html(resultado);

yo quiero poder pasar los valores que estan almacenados en id para convertirlos en una variable y para eso utilizo la siguiente funcion

```
$.post( "pagina.php", {resultado:resultado});
```

pero me voy a PAGINA.PHP(url) y me dice esto

> Notice: Undefined index: resultado in C:\xampp\htdocs\empresa\pagina.php on line 3

de verda que he intentado de todo para pasar la variable por la url y nada me funciona no quiero desistir del codigo porq ya tengo la mayor parte echo y solo falta es detalle d pasar los datos a php si me pueden ayudar estare atento a sus respuestas[image: imagen de los codigos]
introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

Comment: En pagina.php prueba ver que trae la variable $_POST con  print_r($_POST ) . ahi te vas a dar una idea con que estas trabajando .

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido(a) Yerlin, te recomiendo no usar imágenes y colocar el código, esto para mejor comprensión y facilidad de ayuda, puesto que se tendría que transcribir el código.

Comment: Tampoco es recomendable realizar comentarios en la sección de respuestas @Kevin :)

Comment: Disculpa, debido a que no tengo la reputación suficiente, se me hace imposible hacerlo en formato de comentario, al menos por lo que tengo entendido

Answer (score 0):

En principio, el ajax parece correcto. Te sugiero que empieces a usar testigos. Me explico. Abre el inspector del navegador (te sugiero chrome) y vete a la pestaña network. A cargar coolers ponle una línea que te haga un var_dump($_POST). En el inspector, verás si el valor de id está llegando o no.
Si te llega, ponle un echo de la consulta y un var_dump del resultado.
Todo lo que ocurra, lo vas a ver en el inspector.
A mi me ha ayudado en muchas ocasiones. Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Crear variables en jquery que contengan dichos datos, esto debe ser suficiente:

```js
    $('#enviar').on('click', function(){
        // creo variables con el contenido del id
        var cantidad = $('#cantidad').find(":selected").val();
        var coolers = $('#coolers').find(":selected").val();

        var resultado = 'Cantidad: ' + $('#cantidad option:selected ').text() +
        ' Coolers elegido: ' + $('#coolers option:selected').text()
        $('#resultado1').html(resultado);

        $.post( "pagina.php", {resultado:resultado, cantidad:cantidad, coolers:coolers});
    });
```

Usa este code y haz la prueba enviando, al final, con inspeccionar elemento de Chrome en Network da click en pagina.php y vas a ver en "Payload" como llegan las variables que requieres, algo asi:

resultado: Cantidad: 1 Coolers elegido: Cooler 2
cantidad: 111  -> id de select de cantidad
coolers: 32 -> id de select de coolers